# How to read mpp file in .net framework 2.0

Tags: vb.net, .net-2.0, ms-project, mpxj

I want to read mpp file in c#/.net of framework 2.0. i am using MPXJ open source, but unable to use it with .net framework 2.0.

How can i use MPXJ with .net framework 2.0. Is there any other way or another application available through which i can read mpp files.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that I used mpxj with .net 2.0 in the past. What kind of errors are you getting?

Comment: Patmortech, I was doing something wrong.Can you suggest me any link from where i can learn how to use mpxj.Is there any way that i will create a mpp file using mpxj in which task and resources are fixed (that will load from my database) or read only and user can't add any new task or new resources,he can just schedule whole task.

Comment: You cannot write to the mpp file format with MPXJ. It is a binary format controlled by Microsoft. However, you can save to an MSPDI xml file which MS Project will open and use just fine.

Comment: If you can edit your question to show the code you are using with information about what error your getting, I can help you fix it. One thing, you will need to make sure that all the other related dlls (the poi and IKVM ones) are also in a place accessible to your app, not just the mpxj.dll.

Comment: Here is the link to some basic samples for using the component (they're in Java, but you could use a C# to VB.NET converter to get you most of the way to VB): http://mpxj.sourceforge.net/getting-started.html.

Comment: currently i am able to read mpp file using mpxj.I have another question that i mentioned in previous comment. I have my own collection of resources and task or in other words i can say that i have my own master data (table) of Tasks and resources,i will choose task and resources from that collection and create a file having these data only.So is it possible that create a mpp file and restrict user to enter new task and resources in it?

Comment: As I mentioned in a previous comment, you cannot create an mpp file with MPXJ. The best you can do is create an MS Project-compatible xml file (MSPDI format). As for restricting task/resource creation in the file within MS Project, I don't think that's possible, but I could be wrong. Regardless, that should be another question here. Looks like you no longer need help with this specific one about reading mpp files.

Comment: Actually i want detail about both reading and writing but it seem reading a mpp file using mpxj is easy that's why currently i am focusing towards locking or restricting new entry of mpp file.